# Mitigating unknown error in power analysis of ATMega328P microcontroller

Tags: arduino, atmega, oscilloscope, signal-processing, waveform

Setup:

Arduino Uno (ATMega328P Microcontroller) running inline assembly instructions using asm statements. Global interrupts disabled. Pin 13 (PORTB5), DDRB5 designated as output used for trigger event for oscilloscope. The oscilloscope is measuring voltage drop of resistor soldered to VCC on microcontroller and using pin 13 toggle as trigger event. Clock of microcontroller is 16MHZ and the oscilloscope is sampling at 1.25GHZ.

Issue:

The traces acquired from the setup above are relatively uniform. However, they give some odd behaviour causing some errors in my analysis. Every 8 or 16 clock cycles, the waveform will peak on the trailing edge. Reading documentation of the microcontroller about the fetch-load-execute cycle does not lead to any nice conclusions. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: What specific code is the microcontroller running?

Comment: Would you like me to post a picture as well?

Comment: @duskwuff I have posted code snippets. Take a look.

Comment: An artifact from sampling?

Comment: Do you have any examples come to mind? The trace above is averaged from 25,000 traces, so I would assume any artifacts would be smoothed out. The large peaks occur deterministically and continuously through a trace 50,000 data points long as well as other instruction traces. The 'artifact from sampling' repeating with such precision seems too peculiar.

Comment: Your scope is synchronized to an event which happens much less often than a single clock cycle. The sampling points aren't exactly the same for each clock cycle, they are *very slightly off*. Tune the µC clock a tiny bit and see if your "odd hills" jump from 4 to 8 or 16 spacing.

Comment: The traces are averaged, wouldn't the averaging cancel alignment  issues or jitter?

Comment: No, because it's a systematic error. The sampling times are slightly off, but they are off the very same amount for every trigger event.

Comment: @Janka Maybe you can clarify. The sampling rate for the oscilloscope is in GHZ where the microcontroller clock is in MHZ, so the sampling rate is much higher than the Nyquist rate which gives nice resolution. Why then would it matter if the points are 'very slightly off'?

Comment: @Mir  Please post code snippets as text, please don't post code snippets as screenshots.  Text is searchable, screenshots aren't searchable.  StackExchange has built-in syntax coloring.

Comment: @Mir: You have 70 sample points per clock cycle. Of these, about 10 are in the timeframe that shows those mysterious spikes. Why do you think these 10 sample points are showing the real signal?

Comment: @Janka The total trace is 50,000 data points long, and the spikes repeat continuously throughout. I have no other reason to think the points are anything but valid. From the raw trace to the average is only one step. Why wouldn't this trace be valid? Are you hinting that the average is misleading due to the systematic error and that before I worry about this peak I should correctly align the traces?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I will repost formatted code in place of the screenshots soon. However, the screenshots contain all the information. Only missing pieces are just more repeated instructions. The Arduino IDE validates the code as correct.

Comment: Because the sample points aren't the same for each clock you measure, they are *slightly off*. That's because your don't trigger on the clock but on a much much slower signal. And of course it isn't averaged out, because it's the same for each trigger cycle you have.

Comment: @Janka I am looking at my raw traces before averaging and it seems they are off slightly by random intervals like you said. I need to align them. This was the purpose of the trigger event but obviously did not work. What mechanism would I use to perform alignment. Also, should I create a new post?

Comment: You had to trigger on the clock itself. If you can still see peaks on the supply current which shouldn't be there, you may have found something. The problem I expected was coming from using a trigger event only each thousand clocks or so, so the µC and the scope aren't synchronized over milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion would be that it has nothing to do with the instructions at all. Something else in the microcontroller is becoming active every 8 and/or 16 clock cycles.

A couple of possibilities that come to mind are:

- A timer/counter peripheral has its clock prescaler set to 8.
- One of the timer/counter peripherals is rolling over every 8 or 16 clock cycles.
- The SPI peripheral has its clock prescaler set to 16.
- The TWI (aka. I<sub>2</sub>C) peripheral has its clock prescaler set to 16.
- The CKDIV8 fuse is programmed.

Comment: Thank you for giving an answer. I will research these and come back with an update. I also agree with your assumption it has nothing to do with the instructions. Viewing the compiled code hex dump reveals there are no instructions partitioning the block of adds instructions.

Comment: Quick update: I am looking into all the hardware components and attempting to turn off unnecessary peripherals with the Low Power library. Once completed, I will come back with more details.

Comment: Turned off all timer peripherals, TWI, SPI and the data remains consistent. Will check alignment issues above hinted by @Janka. Thank you again for the ideas.